# Issue with React Navigation 5: Bottom tab navigator not rendering correctly showing a small box with a shadow

Tags: react-native, mobile, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

So Im using `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs` to create a simple bottom tab navigator between two screens and im getting this weird look:

[emulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWQtm.png)

Im using a very simple example, here's the code for my first and second screen:

```js
    const ScreenOne = () => {
      return <Text>Screen 1</Text>;
    };
    
    const Favorites = () => {
      return <Text>Favorites</Text>;
    };
```

and here's the code used for my bottom navigator:

```js
    const RootNavigator = () => {
      return (
        <BottomTabs.Navigator
          initialRouteName="Screen One">
          <BottomTabs.Screen name="Screen One" component={ScreenOne} />
          <BottomTabs.Screen name="Favorites" component={FavoritesScreen} />
        </BottomTabs.Navigator>
      );
    };
```

Here's my component in **App.js**

```js
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer theme={{colors: {background: 'white'}}}>
          <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1}}>
            <RootNavigator />
          </View>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;
```

Why is this happening, and is there anyway to fix this using `screenOptions` prop or the `options` prop in each individual screen?

Comment: try removing styles above from the view above `<RootNavigator />` in your `App.js`. I think the `backgroundColor: "white"` is the reason for this.

Comment: @KartikeyVaish I did, still not working :(

Comment: Check the `Snack` link that I provided in my answer...That's working perfectly fine

Comment: @KartikeyVaish Yes i just did, it works. But in my case I'm not using expo, I'm using react-native cli that might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/bottom-tabs-example) is an implementation for above Bottom Tabs

Your `RootNavigation.js` should look like this -

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { useTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import ScreenOne from '../screens/ScreenOne';
import Favourites from '../screens/Favourites';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function RootNavigation() {
  const { colors } = useTheme();

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.background }}>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="ScreenOne" component={ScreenOne} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Favourites" component={Favourites} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </View>
  );
}

export default RootNavigation;
```

Your `App.js` should look like this -

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import RootNavigation from './navigation/RootNavigator';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootNavigation />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: I did exactly that, and I'm still getting the same result. Note that im using react-native cli and not expo, it works fine with expo.